Likelihood ratio test for samples from two different populations
This is basically exactly same as the post here. The answer given over there was not accurate as the null distribution specifically states $\mu_0=\mu_1=0.$
I have attempted it but am not sure if the solution is right.

Problem:
Let $X_1, X_2, \cdots , X_n$ and $Y_1, Y_2, \cdots , Y_n$ be independent random samples from two normal distributions $N(\mu_1,\sigma^2)$ and $N(\mu_2,\sigma^2),$ respectively, where $\sigma^2$ is the common but unknown variance.
(a) Find the likelihood ratio $\Lambda$ for testing $H_0 : \mu_1 = \mu_2 = 0$ against all alternatives.
(b) Rewrite $\Lambda$ so that it is a function of a statistic $Z$ which has a well-known distribution.
(c) Give the distribution of $Z$ under both null and alternative hypotheses.

(a) and (b) The random variable $\Lambda^{1/n}$ (as derived previously) comes out to be
$$
\begin{align}
\Lambda^{1/n} &= \dfrac{\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n(X_i - \bar{X})^2 + \sum_{j=1}^n(Y_j - \bar{Y})^2}{\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 + \sum_{j=1}^n Y_j^2} \\
&= \dfrac{\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n(X_i - \bar{X})^2 + \sum_{j=1}^n(Y_j - \bar{Y})^2}{\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n(X_i - \bar{X})^2 + \sum_{j=1}^n(Y_j - \bar{Y})^2 +n(\overline{X}^2+\overline{Y}^2)} \\
&= \dfrac{1}{1+n\cfrac{\overline{X}^2+\overline{Y}^2}{\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n(X_i - \bar{X})^2 + \sum_{j=1}^n(Y_j - \bar{Y})^2}} \\
&= \dfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{n \left(\overline{X}^2+\overline{Y}^2\right) \Big/ \sigma^2}{(n-1)\left( \displaystyle \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i - \bar{X})^2}{n-1} + \frac{\sum_{j=1}^n(Y_j - \bar{Y})^2}{n-1} \right ) \Bigg/ \sigma^2} }
\end{align}
$$
so that we can base our test on the statistic
$$
Z = \cfrac{n \left(\overline{X}^2+\overline{Y}^2\right) \Big/ \sigma^2}{\left( \displaystyle \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i - \bar{X})^2}{n-1} + \frac{\sum_{j=1}^n(Y_j - \bar{Y})^2}{n-1} \right ) \Bigg/ \sigma^2}.
$$
Now it is known that $\overline{X}$ and $X_i-\overline{X}$ are independent. Obviously, $\overline{X}$ is independent of $Y_j-\overline{Y}$ and $\overline{Y}$. So the numerator and denomenator of the expression for $Z$ above are independent. The ratio is a ratio of two independent random variables with chi-squared distribution and hence has an F-distribution under null.
(c) As mentioned above, $Z$ has an F-distribution under null. Under alternative, it has the so called non-central F-distribution. I suppose this is used to find the power of the test.
My quandry:
I am not confident about the test statistic $Z$ that I have derived. This is especially in light of the fact that the text derives the statistic for the null $\mu_1 = \mu_2$, but unknown mean. In that case, it turns out to have a t-distribution. But here, I am getting a statistic that has F-distribution with the only change that now, the null has a known mean of $0$ i.e it is not unknown anymore.
I would greatly appreciate any feedback about the same.

Looking through at a glance, there seems to be no error in the calculation or the conclusion either (Others may confirm or refute that; or I might after I look carefully). And there is a huge difference between constraining the means to a certain value and imposing equality between two means - the corresponding parameter spaces are different.

That was embarrassing. I changed it right away. Sorry about that. I usually do not make such mistakes but that's what happens when we type it in a hurry. :(
